# What data is being signed in git signed tags?

Tags: git, gpg-signature

I would like to know what exactly is signed inside git signed tags. Let's analyze Linux v4.14-rc3 signature.

```
$ git show v4.14-rc3 | head -n 20
tag v4.14-rc3
Tagger: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>
Date:   Sun Oct 1 14:55:06 2017 -0700

Linux 4.14-rc3
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

iQEcBAABAgAGBQJZ0WQ6AAoJEHm+PkMAQRiGuloH/3sF4qfBhPuJo8OTf0uCtQ18
4Ux9zZbm81df/Jjz0exAp1Jqk+TvdIS3OXPWcKilvbUBP16hQcsxFTnI/5QF+YcN
87aNr+OCMJzOBK4suN1yhzO46NYHeIizdB0PTZVL1Zsto69Tt31D8VJmgH6oBxAw
Isb/nAkOr31dZ9PI5UEExTIanUt6EywVb0UswA+2rNl3h1UkeasQCpMpK2n6HBhU
kVD7sxEd/CN0MmfhB0HrySSam/BeSpOtzoU9bemOwrU2uu9+5+2rqMe7Gsdj4nX6
3Kk+7FQNktlrhxCZIFN/+CdusOUuDd8r/75d7DnsRK5YvSb0sZzJkfD3Nba68Ms=
=7J2+
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

commit 9e66317d3c92ddaab330c125dfe9d06eee268aff
Author: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>
Date:   Sun Oct 1 14:54:54 2017 -0700
```

This GPG signature can be decoded as:

```
Old: Signature (Tag 2)
Version: 4
Signature Type: Signature of a binary document. (type 0x00)
Public Key Algorithm: RSA (Encrypt or Sign) (pka 1)
Hash Algorithm: SHA1 (hash 2)
Hashed Sub:
    Signature Creation Time Subpacket (sub 2) (4 octets)
        Creation Time: Sun Oct 1 21:55:06 UTC 2017
Unhashed Sub:
    Issuer Subpacket (sub 16) (8 octets)
        Key ID: 79be3e4300411886
Hash Left 16 Bits: ba5a
RSA m**d mod n (2047 bits): 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
```

The 79be3e4300411886 key public modulus and exponent are:

```
modulus=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
e=0x010001
```

Using python pow() function we get:

```
sig = 0x7b05e2a7c184fb89a3c3937f4b82b50d7ce14c7dcd96e6f3575ffc98f3d1ec40a7526a93e4ef7484b73973d670a8a5bdb5013f5ea141cb311539c8ff9405f9870df3b68dafe382309cce04ae2cb8dd728733b8e8d6077888b3741d0f4d954bd59b2da3af53b77d43f15266807ea807103022c6ff9c090eaf7d5d67d3c8e54104c5321a9d4b7a132c156f452cc00fb6acd97787552479ab100a93292b69fa1c18549150fbb3111dfc23743267e10741ebc9249a9bf05e4a93adce853d6de98ec2b536baef7ee7edaba8c7bb1ac763e275fadca93eec540d92d96b87109920537ff8276eb0e52e0ddf2bffbe5dec39ec44ae58bd26f4b19cc991f0f735b6baf0cb
print hex(pow(sig,e,modulus))
0x1ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff003021300906052b0e03021a05000414ba5aef12cc8a6983ff47f16a515b1da496a39822L
```

The ASN.1 output in the signature denotes sha1 (1.3.14.3.2.26) and the hash is `ba5aef12cc8a6983ff47f16a515b1da496a39822`. What input data hashes to that value? I would appreciate shell oneliner that would output this value when executed inside Linux kernel git repository.

Answer (score 1):

> What input data hashes to that value?

These are described (not terribly well) [in `Documentation/technical/signature-format.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/signature-format.txt). 
The input is everything in the tag (e.g., `git cat-file -p <tag-specifier>`) except for the part between the cutlines—this exception includes the cutlines themselves.  Moreover the `-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----` should be at the end of the tag, so that deleting from here to the end suffices; several shell scripts, [such as `contrib/examples/verify-tag.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/examples/git-verify-tag.sh), simply exit out of `sed` to strip the signature for verification.

> I would appreciate shell oneliner that would output [the unsigned tag]

The git-verify-tag.sh code has some, but I will copy-paste here:

```
trap 'rm -f "$GIT_DIR/.tmp-vtag"' 0

git cat-file tag "$1" >"$GIT_DIR/.tmp-vtag" || exit 1
sed -n -e '
        /^-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----$/q
        p
' <"$GIT_DIR/.tmp-vtag" |
gpg --verify "$GIT_DIR/.tmp-vtag" - || exit 1
rm -f "$GIT_DIR/.tmp-vtag"
```

It's pretty easy to turn part of this into a single line, since `sed` will read from a pipe.

Comment: The cutlines themselves are not hashed. Note should be taken that RFC4880 signatures do not contain SHA1 of the signed file, but rather SHA1 of the signed file contents and a trailer depending on the signature type. See [5.2.4.  Computing Signatures](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880#section-5.2.4) for more details.

Comment: I thought that's what I said: "except for (the part between the cutlines, including the cutlines themselves)" with parentheses added to indicate binding. English is confusing! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The description of the signature format has recently (Q4 2021) evolved with Git 2.34:

See [commit f6c013d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6c013dfa1a002661543ad5504a918636099c91b) (12 Oct 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 97ab03b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97ab03b12a044ded55de68aac160ffb72c951830), 25 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`signature-format.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6c013dfa1a002661543ad5504a918636099c91b): explain and illustrate multi-line headers
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Rob Browning</sup>

> A signature attached to a signed commit, and the contents of the commit that merged a signed tag, are both recorded as a value of an object header field as a multi-line value, and are subject to the formatting convention for multi-line values in the headers, with a leading SP signaling that the rest of the line is a continuation of the previous line.
> Most notably, an empty line in such a multi-line value would result in a line with a sole SP on it.
>
> Examples in the signature-format technical documentation include a few of these cases but we did not show these otherwise invisible SPs in the example.
> These trailing spaces cannot be seen on display or on paper, and forces the readers to look for them in their editors or pagers, even if we added them to the document.
>
> Extend the overview section to explain the multi-line value formatting and highlight these otherwise invisible SPs by inventing the "a dollar-sign at the end of line that appears after SP merely signals that there is a SP there, and the dollar-sign itself does not appear in the real file" notation, inspired by "`cat -e`" output, to help readers to learn exactly where such "a single SP that is originally an empty line" appears in the examples.

`technical/signature-format` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f6c013dfa1a002661543ad5504a918636099c91b/Documentation/technical/signature-format.txt#L16-L31):

> Signatures sometimes appear as a part of the normal payload
> (e.g. a signed tag has the signature block appended after the payload
> that the signature applies to), and sometimes appear in the value of
> an object header (e.g. a merge commit that merged a signed tag would
> have the entire tag contents on its "mergetag" header).  In the case
> of the latter, the usual multi-line formatting rule for object
> headers applies.  I.e. the second and subsequent lines are prefixed
> with a SP to signal that the line is continued from the previous
> line.
>
> This is even true for an originally empty line.  In the following
> examples, the end of line that ends with a whitespace letter is
> highlighted with a `$` sign; if you are trying to recreate these
> example by hand, do not cut and paste them---they are there
> primarily to highlight extra whitespace at the end of some lines.